# How to find/compare a class property in a List<class>

Tags: c#, class, list, compare

I have a class like this which stores some data to later make a ListView:

```
public class ListData
{
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public int ColumnsNumber{get; set;}
   //And some other stuff!!
}
```

Now, I have `List<ListData> datas` which contains lots of instances of the above class. For making the ListView in detail mode, I need to know the maximum number of required columns. How can I check for this?

At the moment I have:

```
int max = 0;
foreach(ListData data in datas)
{
  if (data.ColumnsNumber > max) max = data.columnsNumber;
}
```

This seems to work, but is there a better way, or built in method or something in C# for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use LINQ for this:

```
var max = datas.Select(d => d.ConlumnsNumber).Max();
```

By this line, you tell LINQ, to map your ListData elements collection into ColumnsNumber collection, and then call Max() which a aggregation method.
In order for this to compile you should add `using System.Linq`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I implement this in case I have a List of Lists such as `List<List<class>>`?

Comment: You can then use SelectMany which will flatten the list for you

Answer (score 2):

For people that prefers the non-lambda version:

```
int max = (from d in datas
           select d.ColumnsNumber).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).  [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) method, for example:

```
int max = datas.Max(d => d.ColumnsNumber);
```

This method throws an exception if collection is empty, though.

Comment: how can i change it to form of `from d in datas...`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Linq Query:

```
int max = datas.Max(data => data.ColumnNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq:

```
var max = datas.Any() ? datas.Max(data => data.ColumnsNumber) : 0;
```

Comment: how can i change it to form of `from d in datas...`

Comment: Doing `Any` and then `Max` on an enumerable that can't be processed multiple times will result in a problem but otherwise this would work.